# Content slider using jquery offset and css problems

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jquery-animate, offset

This is my First question (I did search first and browse for hours)

so I'm trying to build a one page site that has sliding offset sections based on this jsfiddle I found: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/
credits to jtbowden!

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: -150%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
    left: 150%;
}
```

js:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500 );
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
});
```

It does exactly what I want except that when you add more sections they start eating each-others content and don't return back to "div1" like it does when you have just one "container"
heres basically what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/cody32x/MTvG8/ 
I've tried renaming each section and even making new functions for each section but I can't figure it out!

```
    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
    <div id="box6" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box7" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box8" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box9" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box10" class="box">Div #5</div>

</div>

<div id="container2">

    <div id="box1" class="box">2-Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">2-Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">2-Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">2-Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">2-Div #5</div>
    <div id="box6" class="box">2-Div #1</div>
    <div id="box7" class="box">2-Div #2</div>
    <div id="box8" class="box">2-Div #3</div>
    <div id="box9" class="box">2-Div #4</div>
    <div id="box10" class="box">2-Div #5</div>

</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#container2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 300px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    cursor: pointer;

}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 200%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -50%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
#box6 {
    background-color: black;
}
#box7 {
    background-color: gray;   
}
#box8 {
background-color: blue; 
}
#box9 {
background-color: red;   
}
#box10 {
background-color: aqua;   
}
```

js:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});
```

thanks so much! and sorry if I'm not posting correctly on here... I'm new.

Comment: id's must always be unique, you can not have two div's with id `box1`. Use classes in stead, or invent new id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the items moving into another container, change these lines:

```
$(this).css('left', '150%');
$(this).appendTo('#container');
```

... to this:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this.css('left', '150%').appendTo($this.parent());
```

... as right now you work with the same `#container` for both lines of boxes.

To fix the overlapping boxes, change this...

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
```

... into this:

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
```

... as 2px-wide borders also should be taken into account.

Finally, don't forget to remove the duplicating ids from the `div.box`-es. You don't really need them, as you can easily setup styling with classes here.

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wYeeA/), illustrating what's been said, and featuring some CSS clean-up as well.

Comment: AMAZING! THANK YOU!!!! I think all the ids are to style each since the box class is doing something else?? not sure though.